# Cannot find mkl when running make

Tags: makefile, intel-mkl

I am trying to run make on code I've downloaded from the internet (I am on MacOS 10.15.7). I get a bunch of issues like

```
mkl -O3 -no-prec-div -fpp  -qopenmp -xHost -DMPI -module ReleaseMPI -IReleaseMPI/ -c constants.f90 -o ReleaseMPI/constants.o
make[2]: mkl: No such file or directory
make[2]: [ReleaseMPI/constants.o] Error 1 (ignored)
```

and then at the end,

```
ar: creating archive ReleaseMPI/libcamb_recfast.a
ar: ReleaseMPI/constants.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/utils.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/subroutines.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/inifile.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/power_tilt.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/recfast.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/reionization.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/modules.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/bessels.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/equations_ppf.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/halofit_ppf.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/lensing.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/SeparableBispectrum.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/cmbmain.o: No such file or directory
ar: ReleaseMPI/camb.o: No such file or directory
make[2]: *** [ReleaseMPI/libcamb_recfast.a] Error 1
make[1]: *** [camb] Error 2
make: *** [cosmomc] Error 2
```

I don't know how to ensure mkl is found when running make. `echo $MKLROOT` gives
`/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.1.126/mac/mkl`

Comment: I don't see how this relates to MPI besides the fact that you are building an MPI-enabled version of CAMB.

Comment: You are right, thank you.